# How can a system verify an online password using a phone keypad?

Tags: authentication, passwords, hash

I phoned into a financial company's website, and it prompted me to key in my password on the phone keypad, converting the alphabetic characters to the corresponding digit, and special symbols to '*'.

How can they possibly make this work without storing the password in some reversible format internally? Storing a salted hash of the password would not allow this sort of password verification without them checking every possible digit->alpha combination and every possible '*'->symbol mapping.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One possibility is to store a second hashed password. Store the hashed real password, and at the same time map that plaintext password to the keypad equivalent, and store the keypad equivalent as a second hash (and second salt).

Comment: Such an obvious solution that I'm tempted to delete my question out of pure shame. Can I downvote my own question?

Comment: I actually think you asked an excellent question. And, we may be giving that company too much credit!

Comment: If that is the case, that is a very exploitable attack vector

Comment: It would also be possible (but very unlikely) that they replace the alphabets with a specific alphabet and all special characters with a specific character before hashing. For example, replace a, b and c with b, and replace all special characters with a * symbol and then calculate the hash. If this is the case, you can check by interchanging 1 of the letters with another and any special character instead of the correct one on the website and it would let you login.

Comment: @Richie Frame : how so? the salts are different. You mean because the search space for the keypad password (eg., 52-ish keys mapped down onto 10-ish) is reduced in the case that the hashes are made public?

Comment: @mwhidden exactly, a 10 char pass would be ~ 44 million times easier to brute force with the same algorithm, revealing the real characters with ~ 14% probability, regardless of salt length, as long as the salts and hashes are known to the attacker